# Model does not sculpt in one specific area

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting

I purchased this model online (it is a game-ready model that is fully rigged) and when I try sculpting it, it applies the changes to both sides of the model instead of the specific area I want it to. Additionally, I had double checked to see if I had accidently applied the *X, Y, Z axis* to the sculpting procedure, but it performs the changes on both sides regardless if it is enabled or not.

[image: Model]

[image: Sculpting Issue]

Moreover, I had discovered that when bringing the entire model into *edit mode* there are only faces on the left side of the body instead of its entirety (So I guess that has something to do with the sculpting issue, but I'm not sure).

[image: Model in Edit Mode]

What can I do to fix this?

**PS:** I am new to blender so I am inexperienced.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a mirror modifier is in use. If there is, you will need to apply it to make the mirrored geometry real. With the object selected, check your modifier stack in the Properties editor -> Modifiers tab.

Comment: Ok, look's like what you said worked, but now half of the model disappeared. Is there any way to copy that half, invert it, and merge it with the other half? See link of image:  
 https://scontent.fuio1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/296105202_3285985615020227_8415931798631877983_n.png?_nc_cat=101&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=UyMA6PK-4egAX_aXIYW&_nc_ht=scontent.fuio1-2.fna&oh=03_AVKfV2AGupynjZths3FwCeAK33DU1SPL40ITDS5ACwr5JQ&oe=63321B98

Comment: @NicholasMinga That’s what applying the modifier should do. Did you apply it, or remove it?